# Kendo Grid Key enter key press event handling

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have a Kendo grid.I wanted to handle the enter key down event.If a user press enter key inside a Kendo cell.it must focus and put the next cell to edit mode.(cursor should be moved to next grid cell).
I have try this code

```
      $("#list").on("focus", "td", function (e) {         
     $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode == 13) {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 var curCell = $("#list").find(".k-state-selected")
                 var eCell = $("#list").find(".k-edit-cell")

                 curCell.removeClass("k-state-selected");
                 curCell.removeClass("k-state-focused");
                 curCell.removeAttr("data-role");
                 curCell.next().addClass("k-state-selected");
                 curCell.next().addClass("k-state-focused");
                 try {                         $('#list').data('kendoGrid').closeCell(eCell);
                 } catch (ex) {
                 }
                 $('#list').data('kendoGrid').select();                     
                 $('#list').data('kendoGrid').editCell(curCell.next());

             }, 50);

         }
     });
 });
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/2NrLR/1/)

or is there any way to override the tab key functionality with enter key(Because tab key does that function properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function onDataBound(e) {
                $("#list").on("focus", "td", function (e) {
                    $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                var curCell = $("#list").find(".k-state-selected")
                                var eCell = $("#list").find(".k-edit-cell")

                                curCell.removeClass("k-state-selected");
                                curCell.removeClass("k-state-focused");
                                curCell.removeAttr("data-role");
                                curCell.next().addClass("k-state-selected");
                                curCell.next().addClass("k-state-focused");
                                try {
                                    $('#list').data('kendoGrid').closeCell(eCell);
                                } catch (ex) {
                                }
                                $('#list').data('kendoGrid').select(); $('#list').data('kendoGrid').editCell(curCell.next());

                                if ($(curCell.next()).find('select')) {
                                    $($(curCell.next()).find('select')).data("kendoDropDownList").open()
                                }

                            }, 50);

                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            var savings = [{
                month: "January",
                saving: "$200",
                kind: 1
            }, {
                month: "March",
                saving: "$100",
                kind: 1
            }, {
                month: "March sdjhf as dfjh;as",
                saving: "$100",
                kind: 1
            }, {
                month: "March",
                saving: "$100",
                kind: 1
            }, {
                month: "March",
                saving: "$10000",
                kind: 1
            }, {
                month: "December",
                saving: "$100",
                kind: 1
            }, {
                month: "March",
                saving: "$100",
                kind: 1
            }, {
                month: "March",
                saving: "$100",
                kind: 2
            }, {
                month: "March",
                saving: "$100",
                kind: 3
            }, {
                month: "March",
                saving: "$100",
                kind: 1
            }];

            var savingsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: savings
            });


            var grid = $("#list").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: savingsDataSource,
                navigatable: true,
                pageable: true,
                height: 400,
                selectable: "cell",
                toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                columns: [{
                    field: "month",
                    title: "Month"
                }, {
                    field: "saving"
                }, {
                    field: "saving"
                }, {
                    field: "kind",
                    values: [{
                        value: 1,
                        text: "Kind1"
                    }, {
                        value: 2,
                        text: "Kind2"
                    }, {
                        value: 3,
                        text: "Kind3"
                    }]
                }],
                editable: true,
                dataBound: onDataBound,

            }).data("kendoGrid");


            var specialKeys = [kendo.keys.UP, kendo.keys.DOWN];

            function edit(e) {
                //$("#list").find(".k-state-selected").focus();
                //e.container.find("td:eq(1) input").focus();

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: it open up the kendo drop-down list but it appears at all the time.even though i have move my courser away to another location the opened drop down stay as it is.and even if i selected a drop down item.the drop down list keep open.It cannot close

Comment: It doesnt work.Kendo Dropdown keep open all tha time

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#GridID").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

Refer running Code:

https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-prevent-kendo-validation-on-pressing-enter-key

http://dojo.telerik.com/@c0re/iMaBi